# Can I use Linux commands on Android?

Tags: command-line

Android is a kind of **Linux**. So I would be able to use the commands.

Can I use Linux commands on Android? If I can, how do I?

Comment: Android is not exactly Linux. While it runs **on** the Linux Kernel, most of the applications are completely different. Linux itself is not an OS, but is frequently referred to erroneously as one.

Comment: @Downvoter Please explain why downvoted.

Comment: It shows a bit of lack of research.

Comment: Should I delete it?

Comment: No, just let it lie. If the question doesn't do anything, it will be auto-deleted by Community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run some linux commands on terminal application on Android. Install any terminal emulator first then use such commands. However, not all commands could be used. [Here are some for example](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1694251). To run every command linux machine can run, [you'll need to root your device](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-commands-that-can-be-used-on-an-Android-terminal).